# Data not save in frontend using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Data is not save in frontend using angularjs. Here is the angularjs code, it contains three functions, namely: enableEditor, saveData and getTemplate:

```
$scope.editorEnabled = false;
$scope.selected = {};
//Edit code
$scope.enableEditor = function(row){
    $scope.editorEnabled =true;
    $scope.selected= angular.copy(row);
};

//Save code
$scope.saveData = function(row){
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.disableEditor();
    var xArr = [];
    $.each(row, function(key,value) {
        if(key == "actual_result"){
            var actual_arr=[];
            $.each(value, function(key1,value1){
                actual_arr.push(key1+":"+value1 );
            });
        } 
        else { 
            xArr.push(key+":"+value);
        }
    });
}; 

//getTemplete for editing
$scope.getTemplate = function(row){
    if (row.tc_id === $scope.selected.tc_id){//variable for ng-hide or ng-show};
        $scope.editorEnabled = true;
    } else {
        $scope.editorEnabled = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: You should format your question.

Comment: It created some issue after formatted.

Comment: add more text explaining your issue rather than just code